# Xcode (Cocoa) how to write byte to NSData

Tags: cocoa-touch, byte, xcode4.3, nsdata

Xcode...

I want to write one byte (1) to NSData. It seems very simple but im not able to find the proper link how to do it. I try to do that using unsigned char. But that stores the hex value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add bytes to `NSData` use `NSMutableData` appendBytes:bytes length: method